# Blender 3.0 rendering very slow

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I downloaded the new blender 3.0. With the Cycles X render should be a lot more faster. I completed a scene and rendered it. The render is really slow. It's not even faster than thee blender 2.9 cycles. It's taking a lot of time rendering the samples. A single frame is taking about 1 minute to render with just 25 samples. If you think I did something wrong please tell me how do I fix it? Here is my blend file link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NF2Omd07-ElXGyUevU5qKdQt3eiHOu4r/view?usp=sharing

Comment: When I render this with 3.0 on my machine, which has a different configuration than yours, it takes 16 seconds to render with 2.93.6 and 5.5 seconds to render with 3.0.  Are you sure that 3.0 is recognizing your graphics card and that you have GPU Compute enambled?

Comment: You need to render on GPU to benefit from the Cycles X improvements.  If the GPU entry in the dropdown box looks grayed-out then Cycles uses the CPU. But you can still select the entry. In the preferences (*System > Cycles Render Devices*) you can check if your graphics card is supported. My benchmarks for CPU render: Blender 3 -> 37.4 sec (denoising option); -> 43 sec (denoise in compositor) // Blender 2.93 -> 1min 7 sec with denoise option; -> 36.1 sec with denoiser in compositor

Comment: Thanks for solution. It's rendering faster now. But The gpu was enabled in the preferences. I clicked make default. But it wasn't working. I also have enabled auto save preferences. I then I did it again and saved the preferences. Then it worked. Btw thanks for the solution. It is actually my first question on stack exchange.